# Magento 2 How to create a address custom attribute and show them in admin, checkout and account address box

Tags: magento2, attributes, shipping-address, billing-address, checkout-page

I want to create a custom address attribute, I need them visible in all the following places.

1. Admin Addresses.
2. My Account Address Box
3. Checkout address and forms.

How can I implement to have them on billing and shipping address.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom attribute from installSchema or upgrade schema.

```
$eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'type', array(
            'type' => 'int',
            'input' => 'select',
            'label' => 'Address Type',
            'source'=>'Web4pro\Ajaxcart\Model\Address\Type',
            'global' => 1,
            'visible' => 1,
            'required' => 1,
            'user_defined' => 1,
            'system'=>0,
            'group'=>'General',
            'visible_on_front' => 1,
        ));
        $eavSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address','type')
               ->setUsedInForms(array('adminhtml_customer_address','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address'))
               ->save();
```